# remove ID attribute from XML in Unix

Tags: unix, sed

I want to remove ID attribute from a XML file as below. Tries some sed command but it not yielding correct result. need help in correcting my sed command

```
<State>
<Resident Id="100">
<Name>Sample Name</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Street Line1</StreetLine1>
        <City>City Name</City>
        <StateCode>AE</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
<Resident Id="101">
    <Name>Sample Name1</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name1@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Current Address</StreetLine1>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>56666</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
<Resident Id="" />
</State>
```

Tried below sed commands but it not giving me correct result.

```
sed -i 's/^(ID=".*)".*/\1>/' Resident.xml

sed '/ ID.*/d' Resident.xml
```

Want xml like below. All id attributes removed from xml.

```
<State>
<Resident>
<Name>Sample Name</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Street Line1</StreetLine1>
        <City>City Name</City>
        <StateCode>AE</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
<Resident>
    <Name>Sample Name1</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name1@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Current Address</StreetLine1>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>56666</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
<Resident />
</State>
```

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other writes, you should not use `sed`, but if you have no other option.

```
sed 's/ Id=".*"//' file

<State>
<Resident>
<Name>Sample Name</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Street Line1</StreetLine1>
        <City>City Name</City>
        <StateCode>AE</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
<Resident>
    <Name>Sample Name1</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name1@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Current Address</StreetLine1>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>56666</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
<Resident />
</State>
```